# Reflecting the sort of one file in another

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have two files, say `f1` and `f2`.

`f1` has a list of items that can't be compared (they are all alpha numeric, each on its own line). It's companion file `f2` has a list of items that can be compared each on its own line.

I have sorted `f2` in reverse order to produce a file `f3`. I want to reflect this in `f1` to produce a file `f4`.

Example:

`f1`:

```
Dan
Sam
James
```

`f2`:

```
3
1
2
```

`f3` (which is a reverse sort of `f2`):

```
3
2
1
```

I want `f4` to be:

```
Dan
James
Sam
```

I hope this example illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Just to clarify, will `f3` always be numbers sorted in reverse, or might it contain numbers in an arbitrary order (but different from `f2`'s order)?

Comment: It will always be sorted in reverse. The first line will be the greatest number in the file. The second line will be the next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way using the `paste` command.  It should work if your files are simple.

```
% cat numbers.txt 
3
1
2
% cat names.txt 
Dan
Sam
James
% paste numbers.txt names.txt | sort -nr | awk '-F\t' '{print $2}'
Dan
James
Sam
```

Comment: You can use `cut -f2` instead of `awk ...` here.

Comment: Combination of the eduffy's answer and Jordan's comment worked just fine for me. Thanks guys